# Is there a good rails example of running a script from a controller method and saving the result into the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to run a script and capture the result, then insert it into db.

```
 Command:
 @command_result = %x[#{"cd ../../cpanel ; ruby login.rb param 2>&1"}]
```

Is this the right way to do it?  Create a controller method, run this in the method, and then somehow save it in the DB?  If there is a tutorial or example of doing this kind of thing I would love to know about it.  I want to run scripts in a rails application but I'm not sure how to do stuff beyond simple CRUD built in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think in terms of the CRUD model, and the answer become clearer. In your case, you could create a model called CommandResult. Let's say it'd have two attributes; the text of the command, and the text of the output. Inside a controller, you could use it to save your data like this:

```
result = CommandResult.new
result.command = "cd ../../cpanel ; ruby login.rb param 2>&1"
result.output  = `#{result.command}`
result.save!
```

Comment: Here is what I've done:
-->
rails generate model CommandResult command:string result:string
--->
rails db:migrate
--->
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb - Method 'command' added with your answer
--->
config/routes.rb -
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
        get :command, :on => :member
    end
  end
--->
app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb -
<%= link_to 'Command', [comment.post, comment], :method => :command %>
--->
Result: routing error: No route matches "/posts/3/comments/7"

Comment: Got it working with your code, did have to change the result.output to result.result as 'output' didnt exist in my model.  After that its working great, Thanks so much!